# Kafka async send does not retry on failure

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have set up kafka using this way:

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
}

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 1);
    // See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs for more properties
    return props;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<String, String>(producerFactory());
}
```

and on my Service I have autowired the KafkaTemplate

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;
```

but if on send the message fails to deliver for any reason such as TimeoutException the message gets lost.

I found a similar issue described [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4515).

Answer (score 0):

Kafka differentiates betweent retriable and non-retriable errors. For any non-retriable errors such as "Message-size-to-large" Error, Kafka will not retry.

The same holds true for a timeout which can be configured by delivery.timeout.ms. If the configured timeout is exceeded, Kafka does not try to resend the message. You can have a look here: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_retries